# Int() Function MS Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, rounding

I'm implementing the AsymArith round method from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/196652

Now I run into a strange issue with the Int() function: it is supposed to only strip the fractional part, but it changes the integer portion as well.

```
? 131.415 * 100 + 0.5
 13142 
? Int(131.415 * 100 + 0.5)
 13141
```

Can someone explain why the Int() function changes the result of the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably it's Immediate window's magic caused by type cast(dispite 
 ?typename(131.415 * 100 + 0.5 ) is Double)

```
?int(cdbl(131.415 * 100 + 0.5 )) 
13142 


Public Sub test_int()

    Dim t As Double
    t = 131.415 * 100 + 0.5
    Debug.Print t
    Debug.Print Int(t)
End Sub

 13142 
 13142
```

Comment: Actually the use of the Int() function in a function also caused problems, but first casting it to a Double solved it. `Int(CDbl(131.415 * 100 + 0.5)) = 13142` Thanks!

Comment: I agree to "Immediate window's magic" because in a function the cast is useless, it always works fine. I think in the immediate window it splits into `Int(131.415 * 100) + Int(0.5)` that's why the result is `13141`

Answer (score 2):

It is related to the internal rounding mechanism of the int function.

Try for example:

```
print Int(131.415 * 100 + format(0.5, "0.00"))
```

When explicitly setting the rounding yourself, you will get the expected result.

I would refer to do this article:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214118